# Left channel sound comes out of desktop speaker and right channel sound comes out of laptop speaker

Tags: windows-8, laptop, audio, speakers, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Laptop with Windows 8 and a pair of Bose desktop speakers.   When I do tests from the playback devices, the Realtek control panel and a youtube speaker test it will always play the sound for the left channel through the bose desktop speakers and the right channel through the on board speaker built into the laptop.  The same thing happens with headphones.  I've installed updated realtek sound drivers and checked all of my sound settings.  Any ideas?

Comment: This might happen if you haven't plugged in the headphone jack well.

Comment: ...or the headphone/speaker-out socket is damaged.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons this can happen:
 1. Jack not plugged into laptop properly
 2. Damaged laptop jack

How to fix:
 1. Try new a new cable
 2. Make sure the cable is plugged in properly
 3. If all else fails, get a professional to check you jack output as it may be broken. It's an easy an cheap fix though, so don't let yourself get conned